# What amount of physical RAM would a typical "commodity class" server have, as of late 2013?

Tags: linux, memory, hardware

I'm trying to spec out servers for my company's infrastructure group to build.  They tell me anything more than 2GB is too much, which I find ridiculous considering cheap DRAM is about 15 bucks a dimm in bulk and our particular software runs better with more memory.

I tried to find out how much google servers use, and pinning down a number is hard.  Best I could find in a google research paper was that in 2008, their commodity servers were using 2 and 4GB dimms, but the paper never said how many.

I realize "commodity server" is a vague term, but I'm just looking for a rough range in RAM used.  I suspect at least 16GB is going to be the norm.

Comment: I don't even think you can find an entry-level server with less than 8GB of RAM installed these days. What are they smoking?

Comment: I want to say that perhaps they were thinking desktops rather than servers, but even 2GB on desktops is skimpy nowadays.

Comment: I regularly run 2GB VMs for various roles - domain controllers, DHCP servers, etc. Very do-able with proper sizing - though I wouldn't call it the standard.

Comment: This is a weak question. A quick look at the [Dell](http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/servers) or [HP](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/proliant-servers/index.html?facet=ProLiant-DL-Rack#!view=grid&page=1&facet=ProLiant-DL-Rack) server product pages would give you some ideas as to common configurations. If nothing else, asking the vendor you're planning to purchase from would be a great start.

Comment: @MDMarra I run several clusters based on openstack. Mostly 1-2GB machines. But those are all VMs.

If we're talking physical servers, they mostly come in 16~32GB+ flavors

Comment: @SibinGrasic I don't think that it's a safe assumption that we're talking about a physical machine. He is speccing a server that is being given to an infrastructure team. It sounds like he doesn't have visibility into the infrastructure itself.

Comment: Is this for a physical server or a virtual server? These days, it's very common for a physical server to run a few virtual servers, so the typical memory for a physical server will be several times the typical memory for a virtual server.

Answer (score 1):

Cheapest server you can get on hetzner has 32GB of ram.

So my answer would be **32GB**

Answer (score 0):

Without having to get into crazy configurations that include memory daughterboards and quad socket systems, the typical commodity server is configured with anywhere between 4GB and 512GB depending on role and function.